# Couple of issues in my hangman game

Tags: javascript

I'm making a hangman game as part of an assignment I got, though I've run into a couple of problems:

One issue is that I can't make the canvas clear itself when I start a new game (it used to work, but I guess I screwed up somewhere).

Another is that I don't know how to make the correct letters appear where the hidden letters are marked as _.

The code is fairly long so I'll post the relevant parts, but if you want to see it in action, I have posted it to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnrfjg9b/2/).

Code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<section class="task">
    <h3>
        Task 4
    </h3>
    <button id=hangmanbtn>Play!</button>
    <div id="hiddenCanvas"></div>
    <p id="lifePool"></p>
    <div id="buttons"></div>
    <div id="hold"></div>
    <canvas id="hangman" height="500px" width="800px"></canvas>
</section>
```

Javascript code that's supposed to clear the canvas.

```
hangmanbtn.onclick = function(){
    hangman();
};
function hangman () {

    hangmanStyle();
    createbuttons();
    incompleteWord();

/*
*   RESET CANVAS ON NEW GAME
*/   
    var ctx = document.getElementById("hangman").getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, hangman.width, hangman.height);

/*
*   REMOVE CAVNAS OVERLAY & RESTORE BUTTONS
*/
    hangmanbtn.style.display = "none";
    hiddenCanvas.style.display = "none";
    lifePool.innerHTML = "You have 6 lives";
    document.getElementById("buttons").className = "";
```

Javascript code that's the biggest issue, can't figure out how to replace it.
I know the issue here is

```
myWord[i].innerHTML = guess;
```

but I dont know how to solve it.

```
function wordOnClick() {

    var guess = this.innerHTML;
    this.className = "active";
    this.onclick = null;
    for (var i=0; i<saveWord.length; i++) {
        if (saveWord[i] === guess) {
            myWord[i].innerHTML = guess;
            var bool = true;
            winCounter++;

        }
    }
    if (bool != true) {
        counter --;
        animateMan();

    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        document.getElementById("buttons").className = "active";

    }
    if (winCounter === saveWord.length) {
        lifePool.innerHTML = "Congratz, you've won!";
        hangmanbtn.style.display = "inherit";

    }
}
```

Just let me know if you need me to post any other block of code.

Thank you guys!

Comment: I'd suggest this is two questions, that way you can investigate and post them separately - you might find composing a good, succinct question for both will help you diagnose the problem (this happens to me, writing a Stack Overflow question is a genuine part of the debugging process) - but if not, it will be easier for potential answerers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset like this:

```
/*
*   RESET CANVAS ON NEW GAME
*/   
    var canvas = document.getElementById("hangman");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
```

Comment: I see, thanks. But why do we use beginPath afterwards?

Comment: That does not matter, what matters is that you are setting it to the correct width and height.